# Quickblox Audio Calling Issue in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, quickblox

I'm working on Quickblox SDK for Audio Calling and Chatting. Right now chatting is working fine. But when other user calls and I accept it I get the following error. 
Error:

> Set SDP with error: Error Domain=RTCSDPError Code=-1 "(null)" UserInfo={error=SessionDescription is NULL.}

Please guide me how to resolve this as soon as possible. Other than that if other user hangs up or the caller hangs up it's delegates works fine.But the issue above happens only when user accepts the call.I'm using latest Quickblox SDK(2.7.6) and Quickblox-WebRTC(2.2) through CocoaPods. I created another test app only with audio calling feature. That is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. There was an XML Parser library with static methods. It was clashing with the QuickBlox library. After deleting that library it started working again.